# WinForms Designer doesn't locate static resource

Tags: c#, winforms, designer

I have several comboBox controls I want to fill with a 10 items, lets say 0-9.
Instead of configuring it like this:

```
this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
"0",
"1",
"2",
"3",
"4"});
```

I added a following variable in my Form.Designer.cs file

```
static object[] Selection = { "off", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};

this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(Selection);
```

This runs fine, but when I want to **view** it in the designers preview, it says:

*"undeclared variable "Selection"* and deletes all my Add.Range lines [insertangrysmiley]

Why doesnt he find it, its in the same class, right in the beginning...

Comment: Are you bothered about this showing in the designer? if not it might be easier just to include this after `initializeComponent`

Comment: Yes designers don't understand any code(almost) other than what it created.

Comment: Good idea Sayse, thanks to you both

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing

```
    this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(Selection);
```

in InitializeComponent() function

write it outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the static property and do not make `Selection` a member of the Form class. write these two line near each other inside the `Form1.Designer.cs`, at the end of `InitializeComponent()` function.

```
object[] Selection = { "off", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};
this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(Selection);
```

this way it wont give you any error, and you can preview your form!
but still you can't see it in the preview mode, because it's a `combobox`. it's better to use a `listbox` instead! ;)